# SQL Server 2012 Web Management Studio - where are all the options?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just installed SQL Server 2012 Web version, and I noticed that a lot of the options that were in the previous versions of SQL Server Management Studio aren't available in this version.

Simple things like right-clicking on a table and choosing "Design", or "Edit top 200 rows" and "Select top 1000 rows".

Do I need to install something else? Are these options in other places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you connecting to a SQL Azure database? Because those options aren't available for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is the things you listed would fall under "SQL Query edit and design", which according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Mgmt_tools) feature list from MSDN is not available in Web Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: download and install the Management Studio Express package (ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe) from 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062.